# Xamarin Android This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've seen a bunch of posts about this but so far nothing has worked for me. The full error I get is:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

We upgraded the Android packages and it caused this to happen.

Here's my MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

And my styles looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
  <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
  <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
       which is used to tint widgets -->
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
       colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
  <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You might wanna add the whole activity cs file code here otherwise we would just be speculating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `windowActionBar` not the same as `android:windowActionBar`.

`AppCompat` stuff looks at the app namespace attribute not the `android` one. This makes it possible to specify the attribute even in platforms that didn't originally have it. It's how it allows for backporting of things like `colorPrimary`.

Please notice your `MainTheme.Base` have this Comment `<!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->` you should delete `android:`If you're using AppCompatActivity after 22.1 support library

Your code of `style.xml` like following code.

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```